# How do I stay longer than 90 days in Norway with an EU passport?

Tags: europe, eu-citizens, freedom-of-movement

I am a dual U.K/U.S citizen and wish to spend longer than ninety days on a ski trip in Norway this winter. For the purposes of the trip Brexit shouldn’t be relevant as there will no doubt be a significant grace period before any changes are implemented. What process do I need to go through to legally stay for 110 days, bearing in mind I will be traveling consistently and will have no particular residence address other than the AirBnB or hotel I will be in on any given night? Thank you for any advice you can offer.

Comment: No doubt, no doubt... Until the dust has settled, anything is possible :-(

Comment: As things stand, Britain leaves on 29th March 2019. If no withdrawal arrangement is put in place before that (and that is perfectly possible) then it's anybody's guess what the situation will be on 30th March. It's far from clear what will happen even with a withdrawal agreement in place.

Comment: "[Citizens of UK](https://www.norway.no/en/uk/services-info/visitors-visa-res-permit/res-permit/) do not need a residence permit, but must register with the police within three months."

Comment: I gather that, but presumably you would need an actual local residence to register with the local police? Otherwise what are you registering, that you’re in town for a night?

Comment: The Schengen 90-day visitor's visa is set in stone - you can't meddle with it. [This site](https://www.nomadicmatt.com/travel-blogs/how-to-legally-stay-in-europe-for-more-than-90-days/) has some suggestions on how to work around it. You might find something useful there, but note the comments on overstaying in the Nordic countries - not a good idea!

Comment: @CannonFodder: Not really relevant because the OP has freedom of movement.

Comment: @RueKennington: Are you saying that you plan to be moving around within Norway continually throughout your stay?

Comment: @HenningMakholm, yes

Comment: You can just give the address you happen to have at the time. It is not unheard of to live in a hotel for a while. You would need to show that you can support yourself and have health insurance (I think).

Comment: @TomasBy: The NHS covers only people who are resident in the UK, no matter what their nationality are.

Comment: That isn’t an issue. Travel insurance is cheap and easily arranged.

Comment: Will you be arriving on March 9 or earlier?

Answer (score 8):

According to https://www.udi.no/en/word-definitions/registration-certificate-for-eueea-nationals/ you need to **register with the police** as an EEA national living in Norway for more than three months.

It says explicitly that you need to register only once, so presumably it will not be a problem that you move around *within* norway after having registered.

(The registration certificate is not a permit that can denied; it is just a receipt that documents you have told the police that, "I am going to be around").

Comment: Thank you!! This is wonderfully helpful as well as being wonderful news.

Comment: @RueKennington: Unfortunately it seems that what I wrote first is not true. I will edit the answer.

Comment: They cannot deny him the certificate but they can detain and deport him, no? (well, unlikely they will deport a UK citizen).

Comment: @TomasBy: Only if they have a particular reason to do so. The freedom of movement directive gives him an _automatic_ right to reside in Norway; the only requirement is that he _tells_ the authorities he's there (and satisifies the other conditions of the directive, in particular having health insurance).

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Note that this is the situation as long as the UK is in the EU or EEA, or, presumably, during the expected but not yet confirmed transition period. If the UK exits the EU with a deal and without a transition period, then all bets are off.